# Cast Partial<T> to T for an anonymous type

Tags: typescript

I have an array of values of a partial type that is not explicitly defined anywhere. (In my case, it's the `.value` of an Angular `FormArray<FormGroup<...>>`, but it doesn't really matter).

The type that I have could be spelled out as `Partial<{ foo: string; bar: string; baz: string; buz: string }>[]`. Now, I am only interested in the values that actually contain data, so I do this:

```
const myArray: Partial<{ foo: string; bar: string; baz: string; buz: string }>[] 
    = ...;
const filteredArray = myArray.filter((x) => x.foo && x.bar && x.baz && x.buz);
```

Obviously, `filteredArray` will not contain any objects with `undefined` fields. However, TypeScript still infers the type of `filteredArray` as `Partial<{ foo: string; bar: string; baz: string; buz: string }>[]`, same as `myArray` - because the compiler has no insight into the semantics of the `.filter(1)` method, it cannot infer that the actual type of `filteredArray` is the more specific type `{ foo: string; bar: string; baz: string; buz: string }[]`.

Now, of course, the compiler can be helped along like this:

```
const correctlyTypedArray = filteredArray 
    as { foo: string; bar: string; baz: string; buz: string }[];
```

However, this requires me to spell out the entire structure of the anonymous type, which is very inconvenient. In this case, the interface only has four fields, but in actual practice, it may be much more than that. This makes the cast ridiculously unwieldy, and also requires me to change each site where such a cast happens every time something about the anonymous type changes.

Obviously, I could create a definition somewhere and just declare `type Frobnicator = { foo: string; bar: string; baz: string; buz: string }`, which enables me to just cast `filteredArray as Frobnicator[]`, but that still adds a maintenance burden and is annoying busywork.

How can I cast a value of type `Partial<T>` (or `Partial<T>[]`) to `T` (or `T[]`), without having to spell out the type `T`?

Comment: Is the [`Required`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) utility type what you're looking for?

Comment: Maybe - but how can I say `Required<T>` without saying `T`?

Comment: In your case it's `typeof myArray[number])`, you could also combine `Pick` if you don't intend to validate _every_ property: https://tsplay.dev/WGYyXN.

Comment: @Lesiak I define an Angular reactive form like `public myForm = new FormArray([new FormGroup({ foo: "", bar: "" })])`. If I then access `myForm.value`, I get a value of type `Partial<{ foo: string; bar: string }>[]`, but I have not declared this type anywhere myself (Angular creates it for me using type-level magic). I could declare this type, but then I would have to change both the (very long) declaration of `myForm` *and* the type declaration whenever I add a field to the form. It's inconvient.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see, I can cast `myArray as Required<(typeof myArray[number])>[]`! Amazing, that's just the trick I was looking for. Thank you! (You may want to add this as an answer, as I think it's the cleanest solution so far. - Actually, mb21's solution is better for the particular case of `.filter`, but yours is a more universal solution.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [`Required<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) (the opposite of `Partial<T>`).

But since you're filtering on an array, you need to move the filter function out and put a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) on it:

```
type PartialWidget = typeof myForm.value
type Widget = Required<PartialWidget>

const isWidget = (x: Partial<Widget>): x is Widget =>
  x.foo && x.bar && x.baz && x.buz

// usage:
myArray.filter(isWidget)
```

Comment: Upvote. That's the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you! I accept this because it's very useful for my particular question regarding the `.filter(1)` method, even though it doesn't work in all other cases where one may turn a `Partial` into a `Required` type. @jonrsharpe submitted a more universal solution as a comment, that I hope he will also choose to turn into an answer (such that future people who land here via search may also find a solution for their more general problems).

Comment: It's true that writing `as Required<Widget>` instead of using a dedicated function with a type predicate is shorter. However, it's also more dangerouse as the `as` keyword is basically telling the compiler that you know better, and in the function that part is somewhat more isolated...

Comment: I'm not arguing that; but given that my original question asked how one could cast `Partial<T>` to `T` *in general*, your answer doesn't fully answer it. Therefore, other people who land here via Google may not be helped because their problem doesn't involve `.filter(1)`. But mine does, and yours is a great answer for it, thanks!

Comment: By the way, this can be written in one line as `const filteredArray = myArray.filter((x: Partial<(typeof myForm.value)[number]>): x is Required<(typeof myForm.value)[number]> => !!x.foo && !!x.bar && !!x.baz && !!x.buz);`, although it requires spelling the anonymous type twice.

Answer (score 0):

A little hacky but a generic function that asserts the array items as required does the trick too.

```
function asRequired<T extends unknown[]>(
  partial: T,
): T extends Partial<infer U>[] ? Required<U>[] : never {
  return partial as ReturnType<typeof asRequired>;
}

declare const myArray: Partial<{
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
  baz: string;
  buz: string;
}>[];

const filteredArray = asRequired(
  myArray.filter((x) => x.foo && x.bar && x.baz && x.buz),
);

// filteredArray: Required<{ foo: string; bar: string; baz: string; buz: string; }>[]
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM4CUCmBHEMBOmAJgDwAqimAHlJmEaouANZhwDuYA2gLoB8ACgBQiRAAdk%20WMgA2ALkRkANEICUCitVr1GABUnSZJGGGCZ8iAKp9eiAPyIsuAsRLXbCsJgBu5xAG8RREIoEHwkCSkYWRRGLFDwsgBPMUwSKBTMOGBYpzxCIj4AbiEAXyEhIkwIGUlMRAgEVChEAFskgEF8fGQkhX0o2RJA0WA4OAVm-BMAcxLRACNJSahpsDmgpYAvFbWNxZAdxCnZktKbHhKhRrBmxGAYGVoCrp6kxABeXJx84mFRdqvXoAOgeT3MAgEVFUnz4iCooPGiAAZMj4cClhZUejtii0QiFodVCpVFcAPRk%206PZ7EIF9Rw-Fykfz3ca7U6ITHs9ZFTnII4nHmcw7cuaIc68IRAA)